# Does altering a stored procedure expire cached execution plans?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-execution-plan

Does executing a `ALTER PROCEDURE` statement for a stored procedure cause all cached execution plans for that stored procedure to become invalid and expire in SQL Server 2008 / 2005?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

You can verify this by doing

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats 
where object_id = object_id('YourProc', 'P')
```

before and after.

From [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293624.aspx)

> [situations in which plans would be removed from cache include] global operations like running `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` to clear all plans from cache, as well as changes to a single procedure, such as `ALTER PROCEDURE`, which would drop all plans for that procedure from cache.

Comment: Whilst I do believe you (as you have a great reputation) is this documented on MSDN anywhere

Comment: Yes it will be. Will find a link.

Comment: @Aaron - Doesn't explicitly mention `ALTER PROC` that I can see.

Comment: I think the `TABLE` or `VIEW` line is intended to mean any schema change. You can verify with the trace events that the schema changed subclass is what occurs.

Comment: Well, at least you will see SP:CacheRemove events (not necessarily an explicit recompile).

Comment: @Aaron - Yep. I was just hoping to find an absolutely unambiguous quote but no luck so far [even in this white paper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee343986%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @Kane - [Found it absolutely unambiguously stated here!](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293624.aspx) `... These situations included global operations like running DBCC FREEPROCCACHE to clear all plans from cache, as well as changes to a single procedure, such as ALTER PROCEDURE, which would drop all plans for that procedure from cache. ...`

Comment: FYI I filed a bug against the documentation. http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/687418/ ... feel free to vote/comment.

Comment: The Connect item has been updated with a commitment to correct the documentation.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, but what about stored procedures which use dynamic SQL where chucks of SQL code are added to (or removed from) the resulting SQL statement? Depending on input parameters same sproc may generate different ad-hoc SQL statements. This can be the case with sprocs used for searching and filtering data to be displayed in UI grids. When such sproc is dropped and created again (e.g. with updated code), are those previously cached plans for every individual sproc calling case also removed from cache? I don't think so.

Comment: @andrews That is easy to test, right? Remember that something a procedure calls via `sys.sp_executesql` does not "belong" to that stored procedure; the question wasn't about dynamic SQL. If you drop/create or alter the procedure, you'll see the `proc` plan disappear, but any `adhoc` or `prepared` plans that resulted from dynamic SQL will remain, since they are not directly associated with the procedure (and can be shared with other procedures, or ad hoc code, that calls the exact same statements with the exact same session settings).

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Of course this is easy to test yourself:

1. Create a procedure
2. Execute it a few times
3. Confirm it is cached by checking sys.dm_exec_cached_plans
4. Alter the procedure
5. The row in sys.dm_exec_cached_plans is gone

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.blat AS SELECT 1; 
   GO 
   EXEC dbo.blat; 
   GO 5

   SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS p 
   CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(p.plan_handle) AS s 
   WHERE [sql].[text] LIKE '%dbo.blat%';

   -----
   1

   ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.blat AS SELECT 22;
   GO

   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS p
   CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(p.plan_handle) AS s
   WHERE [sql].[text] LIKE '%dbo.blat%';

   -----
   0
   ```

But if your procedure has dynamic SQL, the main `Proc` plan will disappear, but child plans (`Adhoc` / `Prepared`) will remain.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.what
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT x FROM dbo.flange;';
  EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
END
GO

DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
GO
EXEC dbo.what;
GO
SELECT objtype, c = COUNT(*) 
  FROM sys.db_exec_cached_plans AS p
  CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(p.plan_handle) AS t
  WHERE t.text LIKE N'%flange%'
  GROUP BY objtype;
GO
```

Results:

```
objtype  c
-------  ----
Adhoc    1
Proc     1
```

Now, alter the procedure (but in such a way that it still produces the same SQL):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.what
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT id FROM dbo.flange2;';
  EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
END
GO
```

The query above yields:

```
objtype  c
-------  ----
Adhoc    1
```

Of course this is not a permanent state - other queries and other memory pressure on the system will dictate how long those ad hoc queries stay in the cache.

Answer (score 1):

It does - but there may be other factors.

Sometimes with severe performance problems, I've found that explicitly running `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` can vastly improve performance of the system. Of course you can also explicitly clear the cache for a single sproc if you know it's having problems.

Comment: Is this in a situation where the plan cache is full of a lot of single use adhoc queries or something? If so optimise for adhoc workloads could be an option.

Comment: To be honest I've seen this a few times, spent a lot of time on it the first time trying to resolve - had contractors in and everything. We never got to the route cause only discovered that after a lot of database updates sometimes it was necessary to call `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`.